# Getting coordinate information of UK places from DBpedia via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, ontology, dbpedia, opendata

I have a list of places in the UK. I want to get their latitude and longitude information from the http://dbpedia.org.
I have just started to learn SPARQL, and I am not very familiar with the DBpedia. Currently, I am trying to retrieve at least one place, but so far no success. If I manage to get one place, then I will try to get all the places.

**The list of places are like the following:**

```
Llandysul
Rostrevor
Lee on the Solent
.
.
.
```

What I want to get is The place name, Latitude, Longitude.
How can achieve this with the SPARQL?

I have tried the following query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql getting at least the information of one place (Llandysul) but even this did not work.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX geo:  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?place ?lat ?lng
WHERE { 
 ?place a dbo:Place.
 ?place rdfs:label "Llandysul".
 ?place geo:lat ?lat .
 ?place geo:long ?lng .
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can get the information of one place initially, and in the next step information of all place inside a list? Furthermore, if I could add a condition to make sure the place belongs to the UK, that would be great.

Many thanks.

Comment: Use `"Llandysul"@en` instead of `"Llandysul"`. How large is your list?

Comment: location data in DBpedia is very heterogenous depending on the type of place. prperties like `dbo:country`, Wikipedia categories, etc. can be used and should be combined

Comment: lists: Inline data via `VALUES` or filter based via `IN`

Comment: @Stanislav,  I have 204 places. The "@en" addition returns a city, that worked. Is there a way for processing whole list, or I should write a script to iterate over the list add and process the query?

Comment: @AKSW Combining with the country, makes perfect sense, but how can I write the query. A working query would be very helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: Homework? Looks a lot like it...

Comment: @TallTed sorry mate, when I was a student they didn't teach SPARQL or semantic web, rather assembly and c was our lecturer favourite. If unis are teaching these cool kinds of stuff nowadays... lucky students...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+geo%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fplace+%3Flabel+%3Flat+%3Flng%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fplace+a+dbo%3APlace+.%0D%0A++%3Fplace+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+%0D%0A+++++FILTER+%28+%3Flabel+IN+%28+%22Llandysul%22%40en%2C+%22Rostrevor%22%40en%2C+%22Lee-on-the-Solent%22%40en+%29+%29+.%0D%0A++%3Fplace+geo%3Alat+%3Flat+.%0D%0A++%3Fplace+geo%3Along+%3Flng+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) will get [what you want](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+geo%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fplace+%3Flabel+%3Flat+%3Flng%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fplace+a+dbo%3APlace+.%0D%0A++%3Fplace+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+%0D%0A+++++FILTER+%28+%3Flabel+IN+%28+%22Llandysul%22%40en%2C+%22Rostrevor%22%40en%2C+%22Lee-on-the-Solent%22%40en+%29+%29+.%0D%0A++%3Fplace+geo%3Alat+%3Flat+.%0D%0A++%3Fplace+geo%3Along+%3Flng+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+), but note that you must have the correct label; there are no partial matches (so `"Lee on the Solent"@en` won't get you `"Lee-on-the-Solent"@en`) --

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX geo:  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?place ?label ?lat ?lng
WHERE { 
  ?place a dbo:Place .
  ?place rdfs:label ?label 
     FILTER ( ?label IN ( "Llandysul"@en, 
                          "Rostrevor"@en, 
                          "Lee-on-the-Solent"@en
            ) ) .
  ?place geo:lat ?lat .
  ?place geo:long ?lng .
}
```

As @JoshuaTaylor suggests, you could also use [this query variant](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20geo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fplace%20%3Flabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flng%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20a%20dbo%3APlace%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Flabel%20%7B%20%22Llandysul%22%40en%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Rostrevor%22%40en%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Lee-on-the-Solent%22%40en%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20geo%3Along%20%3Flng%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) ([results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20geo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fplace%20%3Flabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flng%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20a%20dbo%3APlace%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Flabel%20%7B%20%22Llandysul%22%40en%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Rostrevor%22%40en%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Lee-on-the-Solent%22%40en%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20geo%3Along%20%3Flng%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)) --

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX geo:  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?place ?label ?lat ?lng
WHERE { 
  ?place a dbo:Place .
  ?place rdfs:label ?label 
     VALUES ?label { "Llandysul"@en
                     "Rostrevor"@en 
                     "Lee-on-the-Solent"@en} .
  ?place geo:lat ?lat .
  ?place geo:long ?lng .
}
```

There shouldn't be much difference between the two; perhaps a bit faster with the second.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer filter/in over a simpler `values ?label { "Llandysul"@en "Rostrevor"@en ... }`

Comment: No particular reason; the `filter/in` was just the first that came to my mind in the moment.

Comment: Is it also possible make sure the place country is the UK? I limited the coordinates by adding the following filter: ''FILTER (?lng > -8.64 AND ?lng < 2.1 AND ?lat < 61.1 AND ?lat > 49.35 )'', but I would like to see how to join it with the country name.

Comment: Countries are rarely squares, so your filter will be of limited utility. You might try looking at the description of some of the places you're interested in, and maybe add something like `?place dbo:country dbr:United_Kingdom .` to the `WHERE` pattern, but I note that `{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rostrevor> dbo:country dbr:Northern_Ireland, dbr:United_Kingdom }` and other `?place` may not have any `dbo:country` at all...